# Testing preStart function of Akka actor

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor

There is parent actor which in `preStart` creates child actors, one for every "active" user. Now I'd like to write a test asserting that it really happens, I mean child actors are really created for preconfigured users.

```
class IntegrationActor(settingsDao: UserSettingsDAO, childMaker: ActorRefFactory => UserId => ActorRef) extends Actor with StrictLogging {

  val createUserActor = childMaker(context)

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    val e = settingsDao.findAllEnabled()
    e.map(_.userId).foreach(createUserActor)
  }

  // ... 
}
```

I have test like this, but it doesn't work as all is happening off-main-test-thread

```
// mockMaker is already defined/mocked

it should "create child actors for users with enabled integration when started" in {
  // given
  val us = UserSettings(...)
  Mockito.when(settingsDao.findAllEnabled()).thenReturn(Set(us))

  // when
  system.actorOf(Props(new IntegrationActor(settingsDao, mockMaker)))

  // then
  verifyMockMakerCalledFor(us)
}
```

I was trying to assign `CallingThreadDispatcher` to parent actor, but with no luck.

Theoretically I could just `new` this class and test it as usual, but `Actor`'s can't be `new`-ed by hand.

Is there any other way to do this other than extracting stuff to trait with self type being `Actor`? Not sure it's the right way.

Comment: Have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18877040 ?

Comment: Thanks, ended up with similar approach. Looks good for now.

Comment: If you want to just test its creation, and you know its id/path/ref, you can send it an Identify message and check the response (or lack thereof).

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia isn't it similar to checking whether `context.child(name)` option is `Some`? I mean, only when there is real parent/child relation

Comment: Kind of. The difference is that you can only access context.child from within the actor (i.e. your own children), while you can send an identify message from everywhere, even outside your ActorSysyem